# How to delete particular record in azure mobile Service

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services

How to delete particular record in azure mobile Service.
For Example I have a table in azure mobile service called **country** having two columns
    country_id
    country_name

If I want to delete the record with country_id=5. How to Perform this.

//Global Variable

```
 private MobileServiceCollection<country, country> items;
 private IMobileServiceTable<country> todoTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<country>();
```

// Class

```
 class country
 {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string country_name { get; set; }
    public int country_id { get; set; }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to call `DeleteAsync` and pass the item you'd like to delete. In this case, the item that has your `country_id`.

`await todoTable.DeleteAsync(country);`

You can read more documentation here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/#deleting

Comment: thanks for your help. i already figure out like this ` country  item = await todoTable.LookupAsync(tbox_cid.Text);

          await todoTable.DeleteAsync(item);`